# Laravel select unique products with lowest price from one table

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, greatest-n-per-group, laravel-query-builder

**Good day, I'm trying to get unique products with lowest prices.
I'm having a products table like this:**
[image]

I would like to get a list of products with all columns. Now there are some products that have more than one supplier in that case I want to grab the product with the lowest `cost_price`.

So far I have tried this

```
$products = DB::table('products')
        ->select('identifier')
        ->selectRaw('MIN(cost_price) as cost_price')
        ->where('stock', '>', 0)
        ->groupBy('identifier')
        ->orderBy('cost_price', 'asc')
        ->distinct()->get();
```

This query returns me the correct results but I cant add more columns every time I add a column for example `stock` in select I need to add as well in GroupBy and then I'm just getting all products.

**How to do it?**
**Thank you for reading.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `greatest-n-per-group` solution/approach for this problem.

The query;

```
SELECT products.*
FROM products
         INNER JOIN (SELECT identifier, MIN(cost_price) AS minPrice
                     FROM products
                     WHERE stock > 0
                     GROUP BY identifier) AS sub
             ON sub.minPrice = products.cost_price and sub.identifier = products.identifier;
```

The query builder version;

```
$sub = DB::table('products')
    ->where('stock', '>', DB::raw(0))
    ->groupBy('identifier')
    ->select('identifier', DB::raw('min(cost_price) as minPrice'));

return DB::table('products')
    ->join(DB::raw('(' . $sub->toSql() . ') as sub'), function ($join) {
        $join->on('sub.minPrice', '=', 'products.cost_price');
        $join->on('sub.identifier', '=', 'products.identifier');
    })
    ->get(['products.*']);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ersoy your solution is correct and very helpful.